# Oracle EXISTS query is not working as expected - DB Link bug?

Tags: sql, oracle, exists, database-link

I'm completely baffled by the results of this query:

```
select count(*) from my_tab mt
where  mt.stat = '2473'
  and mt.name= 'Tom'
  and exists (select * from company_users@colink.world cu, 
                personnel_records@colink.world pr
              where cu.user_id = pr.user_id
              and mt.name = pr.name
              and mt.stat = cu.stat
              )
```

Returns: 1

There are 0 records in company_users@colink.world with stat='2473', so why is it returning true for the exists?

If I change the query like so, it returns 0:

```
select count(*) from my_tab mt
where  mt.stat = '2473'
  and mt.name= 'Tom'
  and exists (select * from company_users@colink.world cu, 
                personnel_records@colink.world pr
              where cu.user_id = pr.user_id
              and mt.name = pr.name
              and cu.stat = '2473'
              )
```

**UPDATE** Okay, this is really weird.  Just to see what would happen, I executed the query from the other database (the one referenced by the DB Links) and it gave different (correct) results.

```
select count(*) from my_tab@mylink.world mt
    where  mt.stat = '2473'
      and mt.name= 'Tom'
      and exists (select * from company_users cu, 
                    personnel_records pr
                  where cu.user_id = pr.user_id
                  and mt.name = pr.name
                  and mt.stat = cu.stat
                  )
```

Returns 0 (as expected).

Comment: You should probably quote which version of Oracle and the platform you are running on.

Comment: Can you provide table definitions?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm using 10g and I am executing this query in SQL Developer.

Comment: @Tom H. The table definitions are quite extensive and have many irrelevant columns, but for the purpose of this example it's sufficient to assume that only the columns being referenced in the query exist.

Comment: How about the definitions for the columns in your query?

Comment: @Tom H.  stat has the same datatype in each table and is varchar2(10).  user_id is a NUMBER in both tables. name is a varchar2(100) in both tables.  All columns are NOT NULL.  Is this the kind of definitions you're looking for?

Comment: Check the link definition in the database that contains 'my_tab'.  Perhaps it's pointing to a database other than the one you think it points to.

Comment: @Bob I did verify that they each point to each other via the links being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the explain plan for the first query. I suspect there is a bug, and the query plan may show how an invalid rewrite is being done.

Answer (score 1):

The second query in your question is a bit different - it doesn't look at cu.stat at all, and thus the fact that there's nothing with cu.stat = '2473' isn't addressed.  What results do you get if you execute

```
select count(*)
  from company_users@colink.world cu,     
       personnel_records@colink.world pr,
       my_tab mt
  where mt.stat = '2473' and
        mt.name = 'Tom' and
        pr.name = mt.name and
        cu.user_id = pr.user_id and
        cu.stat = mt.stat
```

I think this is equivalent to your first query without the use of EXISTS, and should provide correct results.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Sorry, that particular line is incorrect in my original query.  I will update it now.  Instead of mt.stat being set in the second query, it should have been cu.stat.  I cut out a lot of extra things from my original query but this gives the same behavior.